# linux kernel module not able to find "nvme_ns" struct

Tags: c, linux-kernel, include, kernel-module, nvme

I am writing a module in which I am accessing the nvme device using major and minor number.

The code for the function is

```
src_disk = get_gendisk(MKDEV(si->src_major, si->src_minor), &part);
my_nvme_ns = (struct nvme_ns *)src_disk->private_data;

for (i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
{
    printk(KERN_CONT "%02x", my_nvme_ns->head.ids.nvme_ns_ids.nguid[i]);
}
```

Now, when I try to acces `my_nvme_ns`, it fails with error

```
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct nvme_ns’
         printk(KERN_CONT "%02x", my_nvme_ns->head.ids.nvme_ns_ids.nguid[i]);
```

I have included all the relevant files, including

```
#include <linux/nvme.h>
#include <linux/nvme_ioctl.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
```

Using kernel 5.0.0

what am I missing here?

Comment: Please, add kernel version into the question post.

Comment: E.g. in Linux kernel version 5.3.4 `my_nvme_ns` structure is defined in [drivers/nvme/host/nvme.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3.4/source/drivers/nvme/host/nvme.h#L333). This header is local to the driver and cannot (should not) be accessed outside.

Comment: You simple trying to utilize wrong API. You have to found the one for in-kernel use (outside of the NVMe framework).

Comment: @Tsyvarev, true.. In 5.0.0 also, its in the same file. So does that mean, I will not be able to manipulate those structures for a particular namespace from my module?

Comment: @Tsyvarev what will be my alternate here?

Comment: "what will be my alternate here?" - It depends what do you **actually** want to do with nvme device. Note, that Linux kernel programming is intended mostly for providing different "drivers". If you just want to get information about some driver, then use ioctl or other interfaces provided for user-space application.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, I want more than just to get information.. I wanted to modify it at will, through the kernel module..

Comment: @0andriy, I could not find anything else.. Do you happen to know?