# Why does spin_unlock_bh function enables preemption without calling the scheduler

Tags: c, linux-kernel, scheduling, spinlock, preemption

I was looking into the spinlock code of kernel code (version 3.10.1), and didnt understand one thing.

When acquiring the spinlock through the function `spin_lock_bh()`, it goes ahead and calls `preempt_disable()`. This is the same as other spinlock functions which is used to acquire, for example `spin_lock()` and `spin_lock_irq()`.

But when releasing the lock through `spin_unlock_bh()`, it calls `preempt_enable_no_resched()`, which skips calling the scheduler to preempt.
That is not the case for the other corresponding release functions (like `spin_unlock()` and `spin_unlock_irq()`). They call the regular `preempt_enable()` function which calls `__schedule()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`local_bh_disable()` increments `preempt_count` counter by a specific value, also `preempt_disable()` increments it by `1`. That's what `__raw_spin_lock_bh()` does.

`preempt_enable()` function *(which is invoked from `__raw_spin_unlock()` and `__raw_spin_unlock_irq()`)* invokes `preempt_check_resched()`. But there is no need to try to schedule when preemption is still disabled. It will be done inside `_local_bh_enable_ip()` on function exit.

Looking at [source code](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/source/include/linux/preempt.h#L73) you can see that the real [**"BH" spinlock**](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/source/include/linux/spinlock_api_smp.h#L173) call sequence is:

```
spin_release(&lock->dep_map, 1, _RET_IP_);
do_raw_spin_unlock(lock);
preempt_enable_no_resched();
    \____barrier();
    \____dec_preempt_count(); // <--- decrease counter, but we can't schedule here
local_bh_enable_ip();
    \____sub_preempt_count() // <--- real disabling preemption
    \____preempt_check_resched(); // <--- schedule
```

But f.e. [**"IRQ" spinlock**](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10.108/source/include/linux/spinlock_api_smp.h#L165) call sequence:

```
spin_release(&lock->dep_map, 1, _RET_IP_);
do_raw_spin_unlock(lock);
local_irq_enable();
preempt_enable();
    \____barrier();
    \____dec_preempt_count(); // <--- real disabling preemption
    \____barrier();
    \____preempt_check_resched(); // <--- schedule
```

To sum up: in case of BH-spinlock it just bypasses `preempt_check_resched()` because it's not needed.

Comment: oh yes.. The scheduling for `__raw_spin_unlock_bh()` is done is `local_bh_enable_ip()`. Thanks =, I missed that.

Comment: Mind taking a look at my other question, and suggesting a solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58262330/linux-kernel-module-not-able-to-find-nvme-ns-struct